# Hadoop 3.1 build fail at `protoc --version`

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, protoc

I am trying to compile Hadoop 3.1 from its source code.
Once inside docker container i am building it with maven following included instructions in `BUILDING.txt` inside Hadoop's source code files.
While `Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [  0.458 s]` is trying to build, i am getting the following error, regarding `protoc --version`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.1.0:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common:org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 'protoc --version' did not return a version -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.1.0:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 'protoc --version' did not return a version
```

However, the `protoc` command is working on my installation:

```
$ protoc
Missing input file.
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

Same thing is happening with `protoc` version 3.0.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1):

After not finding the exact solution, here is a workaround.

Hadoop's source code, comes with `./start-build-env.sh`. Upon running the script, a `Docker container` will be launched by it, in which Hadoop can be build with `Maven`.

All the necessary libraries exist in the container, but are only included in user's `$PATH`, and not root's `$PATH`. That's a problem because it comes handy using `sudo` to build the package, and that's the reason that `protoc --version` could not return something.

Now every container launched by `./start-build-env.sh` seems to be temporary, and you can't edit the root's `$PATH` via `~/.bashrc`. A workaround is to launch the container through `./start-build-env.sh` and from another terminal window, log into the container using the command: `sudo docker exec -it <container> bash`. Now you can download a simple editor (like `nano` or `vi` through `apt-get`), and edit the default `$PATH` in `visudo`.

Then the command `sudo mvn package -Pdist...` inside the container, wont stuck in the problem I described above